# Pegar arrays com espaço em php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, back-end

Tenho um código em php que pegava informação de duas colunas diferentes de uma mesma tabela em um banco de dados local, porém o código parece não funcionar quando uma das colunas tem informações com espaço, por exemplo: "Romeu Julieta" mas se estiver escrito: "Romeu_julieta" o código funciona, alguém consegue me ajudar?
Segue o código:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "teste";

$conn = new mysqli ($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql1 = "SELECT abbreviation,image FROM je";

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$i=0;
$resultado = array(array(),array());
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
    $resultado[$i]["imagem"] = $row["image"];
    $resultado[$i]["abrevia"] = $row["abbreviation"];
    $i++;
}


echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

Comment: Acredito que seu problema seja com acentos ou caracteres especiais, tenta desta forma: json_encode( $resultado, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

Comment: Poderia exibir o resultado para conferirmos? Em princípio, não é para acontecer o que foi descrito no código mostrado. O erro pode estar nos dados, ou na verificação deles. Aproveitando, nesta linha vale mencionar que você está criando um array com 2 arrays vazios que não vão te ajudar em nada: `$resultado = array(array(),array());` (se der um `print_r` no array gerado, talvez entenda melhor)

Answer (score -1):

Toda entrada em `json_encode()` [Toda a string deve ser codificada como UTF-8](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php).
Então, para resolver o seu problema, basta formatar a entrada com `utf8_encode`:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "teste";

$conn = new mysqli ($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql1 = "SELECT abbreviation,image FROM je";

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$i=0;
$resultado = array(array(),array());
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
    //$resultado[$i]["imagem"] = $row["image"];
    //$resultado[$i]["abrevia"] = $row["abbreviation"];
    $resultado[$i]["imagem"] = utf8_encode( $row["image"] );
    $resultado[$i]["abrevia"] = utf8_encode( $row["abbreviation"]);
    $i++;
}


echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

Em meu servidor funcionou adequadamente.